# Google Classroom querysubmissioncsv parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Does anyone know what the parameters mean for querysubmissioncsv?

I get this link when I click "Copy all grades to Google Sheets":

https://classroom.google.com/querysubmissioncsv?r=%5B%5B1000%5D%2C%5Bnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5Bnull%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5B%%22%5D%5D%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%5D%5D&authuser=0

Replacing the characters, you get this:

[https://classroom.google.com/querysubmissioncsv?r=[[100],[null,null,null,null,null,true,true,true],[null,[],[],[],[["CLASSID"]]],[1,1]]&authuser=0](https://classroom.google.com/querysubmissioncsv?r=%5B%5B100%5D,%5Bnull,null,null,null,null,true,true,true%5D,%5Bnull,%5B%5D,%5B%5D,%5B%5D,%5B%5B%22CLASSID%22%5D%5D%5D,%5B1,1%5D%5D&authuser=0)

Except for the class ID, I'm not sure what anything else means. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: It's probably parameters of the API request. What do you need to know?

Comment: I'm looking to create a master copy for all the grades of all my classrooms and I want to know what variables I can manipulate.

Comment: I see, then it should be much easier than that. Have you considered using Apps Script alongside the [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started)?

Comment: AppScript has a 6-minute limitation and I have multiple classrooms that I teach. My script used to work but ever since last week, I've been getting RTO because I suspect that the activities I gave this week broke the 6-minute time limit.

Comment: If your script does not work anymore I suggest you to contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en), as it could be related to your domain or account.